# Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException' with message 'Authentication with Google failed. Reason: BadAuthentication'

Tags: zend-framework, google-docs-api, zend-gdata

This is the script that i was run , This is working local machine not online, Please give me any suggestion

```
private function login($user,$pass)
{               
    require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets');

    $service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
    $http = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user,$pass,$service);
    $this->client = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($http);

    if ($this->client instanceof Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets) return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}`
```